# How to get main div container to align to centre?

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have always been wondering how other people get to align to the centre the main div container as the only way I manage so far is adding to the css file the following:

```
*{
padding:auto;
margin:auto;
text-align:centre;
}
```

I have seen other pages using: `*{padding:0px;margin:0px}` but I can't see where or what do they do to centralise the main container.

Could anybody explain how?

Code example:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
<title>This is the main container</title>
<style type="text/css">
*{
padding:auto;
margin:auto;
text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="width:400px;background-color:#66FFFF;display:block;height:400px;">
<b>This is the main container.</b>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Could anybody explain how do they do it in the following page?

http://www.csszengarden.com/?cssfile=/179/179.css&page=4

Comment: also you can wrap you content with <div align="center"></div>, but better solution is below

Comment: on the page you linked to they do use margin auto on the container. However padding auto is not required, and may even confuse some browsers.

Comment: @wheresrhys: Thank you, I cant find it on the css.

Comment: You should install firebug (if you're using firefox). Click on the html tab, then on the wrapper div and in the right panel it tells you all the styles

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Do not use the `*` selector as that will apply to all elements on the page. Suppose you have a structure like this:

```
...
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <b>This is the main container.</b>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can then center the `#content` div using:

```
#content {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #66ffff;
}
```

Don't know what you've seen elsewhere but this is the way to go. The `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` snippet you've seen is for resetting browser's default definitions for all browsers to make your site behave similarly on all browsers, this has nothing to do with centering the main container.

Most browsers apply a default margin and padding to some elements which usually isn't consistent with other browsers' implementations. This is why it is often considered smart to use this kind of 'resetting'. The reset snippet you presented is the most simplest of reset stylesheets, you can read more about the subject here:

- http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: Is is not good practice to apply *{padding:0px;margin:0px;}, to make it more cross browser compatible?

Comment: @Cesar Lopes, in my opinion it is, but there seems to be people who think otherwise. But I'd say go ahead with it.

Answer (score 4):

The basic principle of centering a page is to have a body CSS and main_container CSS. It should look something like this:

```
body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     text-align: center;
}
#main_container {
     margin: 0 auto;
     text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can text-align: center the body to center the container.  Then text-align: left the container to get all the text, etc. to align left.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow =) Please take a moment to read through the [Stack Overflow Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help/) for guidance on how to format your answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would omit the `* { text-align:center }` declaration, as it sets center alignment for all elements.

Usually with a **fixed width container** `margin: 0 auto` should be enough